# calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0,\infty)} \exp(-x)\sin(nx)\,\mathrm{d}\mathcal{L}^1(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

We've had the following Lebesgue-integral given:

$$\int_{[0,\infty)} \exp(-x)\sin(nx)\,\mathrm{d}\mathcal{L}^1(x)$$

How can you show the convergence for $n\rightarrow\infty$?

We've tried to use dominated convergence but $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sin(nx)$ doesn't exist.
Then we've considered the Riemann-integral and tried to show that 
$$\int_0^\infty |\exp(-x)\sin(nx)| \,\mathrm dx
$$
exists but had no clue how to calculate it. So how can you show the existence of the Lebesgue-integral and calculate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ |\exp(-x)\sin(nx)| \leq \exp(-x) $

Moreover, you can easily compute the integral for arbitrary $n$ by integrating by parts twice:

$$ \int_{[0,\infty)} \exp(-x)\sin(nx) = -\exp(-x)\sin(nx) |_{0}^{\infty} +n\int_{[0,\infty)} \exp(-x)\cos(nx) $$

$$ \int_{[0,\infty)} \exp(-x)\sin(nx) = n\int_{[0,\infty)} \exp(-x)\cos(nx) $$

$$ \int_{[0,\infty)} \exp(-x)\sin(nx) = n\exp(-x)\cos(nx) |_{0}^{\infty}-n^2\int_{[0,\infty)} \exp(-x)\sin(nx) $$

$$ (n^2 + 1) \int_{[0,\infty)} \exp(-x)\sin(nx) = n $$

So the integral equals $ \frac{n}{n^2 +1} $

Comment: Next time make sure to write the absolute value in the first place

Comment: sry, my mistake now. you've totally answered my question ;)

Comment: I believe it is okay: one minus comes from integrating by parts, and another one comes from the antiderivative of $ \exp(-x) $

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without computing by Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma

$$\int_{\Bbb R}f(x)\sin(nx)dx\to0$$

for $f$ continuous almost every where